# how to get ajax response in html with out any html code attached to it

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I called jsp page from html page using jquery and ajax which is working properly but the response it is displaying is a html code .see below.I have entered 1 and 3 and the sum of the two number should display 4.but in the text box it is displaying the complete html code with result.how to avoid html code...........

first number: 1

second number: 3

Response

```
  !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"><title>Insert title here</title></head><body>4</body></html>
```

the below is my html code

### AddNumbers.html

```
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <h1> </h1>
        <h2>add two number</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>first number:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="num1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>second number:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="num2" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>result:</td>
                <td><input type="text" readonly id="result" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br> <input type="button" id="Button1" 
            onclick="addNumbers()" value="add number" />
    </form>
</body>
```

### AddNumbers.jsp

```
<body>
<% 
   int n1,n2;
n1=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1"));
n2=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2"));
System.out.print(n1+n2);
out.print(n1+n2);

%>
```

### test.js

```
function addNumbers() {
    alert("hello");
    $.get("AddNumbers.jsp",{num1:$("#num1").val(),num2:$("#num2").val()},doUpdate);
}

function doUpdate(response) {
    alert(response);
    if (response) {
        $("#result").val(response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove all the html tag and add only java code like below one

```
<% 
int n1,n2;
n1=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num1"));
n2=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("num2"));
System.out.print(n1+n2);
out.print(n1+n2);

%>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems **AddNumbers.jsp** contains html (Code posted shows body tag). Remove all html tags from **AddNumbers.jsp**.